# How to draw button theme with gradient sroke and gradient text

Tags: java, android, button

[image]

I want to make this button. If possible in XML. If not possible how can we this with JButton extension class.

Comment: Did you achieve that result? I'm facing a similar issue, but I'd like to apply the gradient only on the text of a `EditText`

Comment: No, I could not. I think I have to work on canvas for this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this picture in `drawable` Folder in res.
copy the picture and past at Android Studio in this folder.
the name needs to be only with small letters.
the on XML code in the button setting write `android:background=" "` and then write drawable in `" "` and then press enter.

Comment: Thank you. But I want it to be dynamic.